# Python: A way to iterate though sublists akin to the 'in' operator?

Tags: python

I'm prowled a bit on the internet, and couldn't find a way to do this. The 'in' operator only works with the surface level of a list, but is a method of checking all sub-lists for a value without iterating over them with for? See example:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> 1 in a
True #this is good
>>> a = [[1,2],[3,4]]
>>> 1 in a
False #I would want this to be true, as there is a 1 in a[0]
```

If someone could point me to a method of doing this save manually iterating, that would great. :)

Comment: a has list inside it and in those list 1 is present

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) operator:

```
>>> a = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
>>> any(1 in lst for lst in a)
True
```

But for anything larger than two nestings I would say use a loop, otherwise the code gets quite messy